# Default positioning for terminal on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome-terminal, 17.10, ccsm

I'm using GNOME. I can't figure out how to set the terminal's default coordinates for opening a new window at a certain position, since CCSM no longer works.

I'm looking to have new terminal windows open at the bottom right as opposed to the default top left of the screen. Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the terminal launcher (terminal's .desktop file) from  /usr/share/applications/ to ~/.local/share/applications/ and edit the Exec field accordingly.

E.g. for gnome-terminal:

Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry 73x31+100+300

This was from don_crissti's answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48984/how-can-i-set-the-position-that-terminal-opens-at

Comment: glad I could help

Comment: I'm on Mate 19.10, after editing the Exec command under ~/.local it works if I select the Terminal icon to launch, but doesn't when hot keys "Win+T" or "CTRL+ALT+T". Any ideas on how to set this for hotkeys?